# Para a Rotação no Eixo Z

Tags: c#, unity3d

Sou novo com os código c# e estou fazendo um movimento básico de rotação no eixo Z no unity 3d, mais estou tendo um problema para parar de rotacionar. O código inicial é esse:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Sysstem.Collections;

public class voa : MonoBehaviour{

int vel = 150;

// Use this for initialization
void Start (){

}

// Update is called once per frame

void Update () {

if (Input.GetButton("right)){

    transform.Rotate(0,0,vel * Time.deltaTime);

    }

    if (INput.GetButton ("left)){

    transform.Rotate (0,0,-vel * Time.deltaTime);

    }

  }

}
```

Qual seria a sequencia desse código, para que na hora que o objeto estiver em 80 grau (positivo ou negativo), mesmo apertando o botão das setas ele não passa desse ponto.

Comment: Cara, coloque o código e não uma imagem dele. Tem muita gente que não consegue ver as imagens por causa de bloqueios. Visite o [tour], veja a [help] e [ask]. Isso vai te ajudar a melhorar tua pergunta. (Sempre que quiser tu pode editá-la clicando em [edit].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O seu código tinha alguns errinhos de digitação e não funcionou aqui diretamente. Bom, tendo eles corrigidos, uma ideia que pode te ajudar é você simplesmente limitar a rotação antes de executá-la. Para isso, acumule o valor da rotação a cada quadro em que isso ocorrer e compare se o valor acumulado excede (tanto no "sentido" positivo como no sentido negativo) a sua rotação máxima. O código a seguir faz isso:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class voa : MonoBehaviour{

    int vel = 150;
    float acumulado = 0;
    public float limite_angular = 90;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start (){

    }

    // Update is called once per frame

    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetButton ("Horizontal")) {

            float angulo = vel * Time.deltaTime * Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

            if( (acumulado + angulo) >= limite_angular || (acumulado + angulo) <= -limite_angular)
                angulo = 0;

            acumulado += angulo;
            transform.Rotate (0, 0, angulo);
        }

    }

}
```

Note que eu estou apenas fazendo essa acumulação no eixo Z (que é o que você usa no seu código original). Se precisar acumular nos três eixos, mude a variável de `float` para `Vector3` e acumule em cada um deles. Note também que eu estou usando a variável "horizontal" ao invés de "right" e "left" (porque esse é o padrão da Unity - ao menos na versão mais recente). E finalmente, note também, que para ter o sinal (positivo ou negativo) basta multiplicar por `GetAxisRaw` (função que retorna -1 ou 1 para indicar o sentido da movimentação no eixo horizontal).

Ah, eu coloquei a variável `limite_angular` como pública, pois assim você pode alterar seu valor diretamente na janela do *Inspector*.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta deu certo, mas apareceu uma duvida!
Se o objeto estiver inclinado no angulo de 90 grau, tem a possibilidade dele rodar em Y. Ex:Um Avião ao virar ele se inclina para o lado e depois vira, teria como fazer esse movimento ao apertar um botão apenas? ele rotacionava no eixo z e virava no eixo Y para ambos os lados.

Comment: Por nada. Bom, eu não entendi direito. Vc quer dizer rotacionar em outro eixo a partir do momento em que o primeiro eixo já atingiu seu limite máximo? Se sim, claro que tem. É só usar duas variáveis e fazer duas verificações (uma dentro da outra). De todas as formas, talvez seja melhor você abrir uma nova pergunta. Lembre-se: este site não é um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas. :)

Comment: Ah, e se a resposta foi útil e te ajudou, por favor considere marcá-la como aceita: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta